# Alternative to aggregate function that doesn't collapse df

Tags: r, count, aggregate

I have person-level data and want to create a new variable that has the number of kids in a family. I have created a dummy variable for kids (1 if age<18, 0 otherwise). I'm currently using the aggregate function, where HH_ID is a household identifier.

```
 No_kids <- aggregate(child ~ HH_ID, data = df, sum)
```

This code works but the data frame collapses whereas I want to assign the number of kids to each observation for that household. Is there an alternative to the aggregate function that doesn't collapse the data set?

Comment: Look at `ave` and read [mcve] on how to ask a question on SO.

Comment: If you merge the No_kids data frame back in with your original, based on `HH_ID` does that not get you what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could do a `merge` after aggregation (so in base R):

```
ag <- aggregate(child ~ HH_ID, data = df, sum)
setNames(merge(df, ag, by="HH_ID"), c("HH_ID", "child", "No_kids"))
```

Comment: Not the most elegant piece of code but adapting your suggestion worked: ag <- aggregate(child ~ HH_ID, data = df, sum)

test <- merge(df, ag, by="HH_ID")
df$No_kids <- test$child.y

Answer (score 1):

another option is dplyr  ...  of course

```
library(dplyr)
> player_df = data.frame(team = c('ARI', 'BAL', 'BAL', 'CLE', 'CLE'),
+                        player =c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'), 
+                        '1' = floor(runif(5, min=1, max=2)*10),
+                        '2' = floor(runif(5, min=1, max=2)*10))
```

and then using group_by and mutate from dplyr

```
player_df %>% group_by(team) %>% mutate(count = n())

Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
Groups: team [3]

    team player    X1    X2 count
  <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1    ARI      A    12    12     1
2    BAL      B    10    12     2
3    BAL      C    14    12     2
4    CLE      D    10    14     2
5    CLE      F    18    17     2
```

Comment: Agh, just a second too slow :)

Comment: You should watch out using n() though because OP has both zeros and ones in their HH_ID group which would both be counted by n()

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dplyr` package:

```
# Create sample data
set.seed(3252)

df <- data.frame(
  HH_ID = sample(1:10, 50, replace = TRUE),
  child = sample(0:1, 50, replace = TRUE)
)

# Count number of children
df %>% 
  group_by(HH_ID) %>% 
  mutate(child_count = sum(child)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```